# Is it possible to assign 4 numerical values to a word entered in a cell in excel that could then be auto totaled?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to write a code in excel that would allow me to keep track of dietary macros of food items eaten throughout the day. For example, if I enter the word Potato in a cell, another table would display the calories, fats, protein, and carbs of a potato. As I add other ingredients, those totals would be added as well showing me the total macros of the meal. Would this bee possible?

Comment: Hi @Ryan Barletta ,, yes it's possible,,,, better create one Master Table has Calories & Carbs of all ingredients ,,,, and in another Table use Lookup formula for the food stuff ,,,   may go with any Lookup formula Older or Recent XLOOKUP ☺

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variety of lookup formulas, such as `VLOOKUP` against your table which stores your information.

Columns G through K is your static table of food items.

Columns A is your ingredient that you type in, while columns B through E are VLOOKUPS to your static table. Row 2 will sum the values below it.

| colA | Calories | Fats | Proteins | Carbs | colF | Ingredient | Calories | Fats | Proteins | Carbs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MEAL TOTALS | =SUM(B4:B31) | =SUM(C4:C31) | =SUM(D4:D31) | =SUM(E4:E31) |  | Beans | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Ingredients | Calories | Fats | Proteins | Carbs |  | Butter | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| Potato | =VLOOKUP($A4,$G:$K,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A4,$G:$K,3,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A4,$G:$K,4,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A4,$G:$K,5,FALSE) |  | Potato | 50 | 5 | 2 | 30 |
| Butter | =VLOOKUP($A5,$G:$K,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A5,$G:$K,3,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A5,$G:$K,4,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A5,$G:$K,5,FALSE) |  | Steak | 250 | 55 | 15 | 14 |
| Steak | =VLOOKUP($A6,$G:$K,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A6,$G:$K,3,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A6,$G:$K,4,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A6,$G:$K,5,FALSE) |  |  |  |  |  |  |

So for Cell B4, input that formula and then drag it over and down. You won't need to retype every time.

The output would then look like this:

|  | Calories | Fats | Proteins | Carbs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MEAL TOTALS | 305 | 66 | 24 | 52 |
| Ingredients | Calories | Fats | Proteins | Carbs |
| Potato | 50 | 5 | 2 | 30 |
| Butter | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| Steak | 250 | 55 | 15 | 14 |

[image: output as pic]

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much, Ill give this a go!

Comment: If this works for you, then please consider marking the Accept Answer flag.